# Are there any video editors that support WebM?

Tags: software-recommendation, video-editor, webm

Are there any video editors for Ubuntu that support [WebM](http://www.webmproject.org/) importing? AKA, I have a raw WebM file that needs editing.

Comment: Import and export or only export?

Comment: @BrunoPereira import and export - I'll edit to make it clearer

Answer (score 5):

I am not sure how much editing you will need to do but [`Openshot Video Editor`](http://www.openshotvideo.com/) ([`package openshot`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=openshot)) [image: Install openshot] supports webm import, editing and export.

[image]

[image]

Not the most powerful thing in the world but can fit some uses.

Comment: Odd, wondering why openshot didn't recognize my WebM file then... ok, i'll look into it some more. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome, if it does not feet the needs edit the question saying so so we find you replacement ;)

Comment: Hmmm... I just installed OpenShot 1.4.3 and it says it doesn't support webm. I installed all the packages that Aptitude suggested and recommended, i.e. `sudo apt-get install openshot blender inkscape frei0r-plugins openshot-doc`... do I need anything else?

Comment: link does not work anymore

Answer (score 0):

The only way I've managed to do it is by [converting the webm file to an MP4](https://askubuntu.com/a/526701/135088) and then using an MP4-compatible editor, such as OpenShot.

Unfortunately, the conversion process is extremely slow—it took my system about 20× the length of the video. But it did work.

Answer (score 0):

if you just need a fast cut without recording - Try [VideoCUT](https://github.com/kanehekili/VideoCut) - It supports mp4, AVCH ,avi, webm, ts

[image: Main Screen]