# Convert WebM to other formats

Tags: webm

I take photos and videos using Cheese on Ubuntu 12.04. They are in WebM formats.

How to convert them in other more conventional formats for making them compatible with other OS and devices (Windows, Mobiles etc)?

I am looking for an easy tool since I don't need to process my files further.

Thanks for the reply.

Comment: WinFF works well in Linux Mint, it's in the Software Manager. It's a GUI for ffmpeg.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I recommend you to download the FF Multi Converter.

[image: FF-Multi-Converter]

have a look at this page :

[FF Multi Converter](http://www.noobslab.com/2013/04/latest-ff-multi-converter-for-ubuntu.html)

Comment: In Ubuntu 16.04, the FF Multi Converter app is not to be found in the Ubuntu Software Center.  Can I still install it on Ubuntu 16.04 by using the Terminal commands presented in the link?

Comment: Meanwhile, I've found this link: https://github.com/Ilias95/FF-Multi-Converter/wiki/Installing-on-Ubuntu It seems to me that this app is "momentarily unavailable'.

Answer (score 106):

### With `ffmpeg`

I think you should do this with [ffmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/).

To install, type these lines in terminal:

```
sudo apt install ffmpeg
```

now you have `ffmpeg` installed, you can convert webm to mp4 by this command:

```
ffmpeg -i input_filename.webm output_filename.mp4
```

Let's say you have your `sample.webm` file in your downloads folder and you want to generate the output to the same folder. You run this command:

```
ffmpeg -i ~/Downloads/sample.webm -qscale 0 ~/Downloads/sample.mp4
```

If you don't want to type this long command every time in your terminal you can create a little bash function to do it for you.

In terminal type `nano ~/.bashrc` scroll down to the bottom and insert:

```bsh
webmTOmp4 () {
  ffmpeg -i "$1".webm -qscale 0 "$1".mp4
}    
mp4TOmp3 () {
  ffmpeg -i "$1".mp4 "$1".mp3
}
```

Now you can do: `mp4TOmp3 GENUINE\ -\ Thleilaxu-k8hrEbXURzg` and the script will convert and save your new file with the same name to the same folder.

Comment: We can perform this converting action without to download the repository you are talking about (only the native ffmpeg library). However, I have to say that the conversion process is very, very, very slow. Maybe with your upgraded files it will work faster? ???

Comment: @Juan what upgraded files are you talking about? The converting and downloading process both are very fast to me.

Comment: I'm talking about I use Ubuntu Studio 16.04 LTS and it has the ffmpeg library included on it. Also, I tried to download the jon-severinsson ppa but the system tells me that it doesn't exist. So... Also, in my system, the process is too slow and frame by frame. I think something is missing into your command line expression. Sorry, I'm not a programmer so I just copy and paste it. I don't have any clue about how to use and/or improve the use of the ffmpeg library. Sorry!!!

Comment: for latest version use `ffmpeg -i your_input_filename.webm -qscale 0 your_outfile_name.mp4` because option `-sameq` has been removed in latest package

Comment: @Vineet Please use -q:a or -q:v, -qscale is ambiguous

Answer (score 6):

You can watch *and* convert videos using VLC.

Install VLC:

```
sudo apt install vlc
```

To convert videos, [this article in Laptop Magazine](https://www.laptopmag.com/articles/convert-video-using-vlc) recommends looking for the `Convert/Save` option in VLC's `Media` menu.